# Event stop firing after parent modified

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to do a simple thing, this is my html:

```
<div id="div1">
    <a id="first" href="#">First</a>
</div>
```

and this is my js script

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var first = document.getElementById("first");

first.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    alert("Hello");
    div1.innerHTML = div1.innerHTML + '<a id="second" href="#">Second</a>';
}, false);
```

when i click on the #first link a second anchor is inserted into #div1, after that, if i try to click again on the #first link nothing appens...

why this?

i have created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkL7bomw/

Comment: `first`'s event listener doesn't exist anymore when you manipulate the HTML drectly.

Comment: apend the element so you don't remove the existing ones and have to rebind event handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first`'s event doesn't exist anymore (the original `#first` is replaced with a new `#first`) when you manipulate the HTML directly. Change the DOM instead of HTML:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href= "#";
    a.innerHTML = "Second";
    div1.appendChild(a);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jkL7bomw/1/

Never add/change elements with `innerHTML` unless you know what you are doing.